Why does this code write the answers more than once instead of just once?
I've just made a C program about finding perfect numbers. It is kinda working, but it writes out the answers more than once(and it writes 24 as well for some reason).
I have very basic C knowledge, I thought it's simple enough.
The code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
        k = 0;

        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                k = k + j;
            }

            if (k == i) {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried placing k to somewhere else, but didn't work, tried to use the return function, but my C knowledge is not big enough

"but it writes out the answers more than once(and it writes 24 as well for some reason)" - Then that printf statement is being reached more than once.  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Your code is incorrect.  It will print if any set of factors add up to i, even though they eventually go over.  You should only check after you have added all the factor.  ie. after the inner loop completes.

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        k = 1; // initialize k to 1 (the smallest proper divisor)
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                k = k + j;
            }
        }
        if (k == i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}

I made the variable k set initially to 1, and the inner loop only iterates from 2 to i-1. This means that k will be the sum of the proper divisors of i when the inner loop finishes. If k is equal to i, then i is a perfect number, and the code prints it out.

In addition to the answers already provided which identify the core issue, this seems an excellent place to take the nested loop logic and split it out into a function, so that that function might be smaller and more focused.
Doing this frequently makes code easier to reason about and debug. The main function no longer has to worry about how to determine if a given integer is a perfect number.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_perfect_number(int n);

int main(void) {
    for (int n = 2; n < 1000; n++) 
        if (is_perfect_number(n))
            printf("%u\n", n);
}

bool is_perfect_number(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return false;

    int sum_divisors = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) 
            sum_divisors += i;

    return (sum_divisors == n);
}


According of the definition of the perfect number

"A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of
its positive proper divisors, that is, divisors excluding the number
itself."

So at least instead of using the signed integer type int you should use unsigned integer type unsigned int.
Also you should declare variables in minimum scopes where they are used.
This inner for loop
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)

is already incorrect becuase the number itself that is the value of the variable i is not excluded from its divisors.
Also the condition in the for loop
for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            ^^^^^^

results in redundant iterations of the loop.
This if statement
if (k == i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

shall be placed outside the inner for loop. Otherwise for example for the number 24 you can get that 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8 (that are divisors of the number excluding divisor 12) that the number 24 is a perfect number.
The program can look for example the following way
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for (unsigned int i = 2, n = 1000; i < n; i++)
    {
        unsigned int perfect_number = 1;

        for (unsigned int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) perfect_number += j;
        }

        if (perfect_number == i)
        {
            printf( "%u\n", i );
        }
    }
}

The program output is
6
28
496


For perfect numbers, check for divisors excluding that number, so instead of for (j = 1; j<=i; j++) use for (j = 1; j<i; j++) and for the repetition part keep the check condition outside the j-loop and inside the i-loop.
int main()
{
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    k = 0;

    for (j = 1; j<i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
          k = k + j;
        }
    }
    if (k == i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
}


Please don't double-space the code. Your code should fit into the snippet box without scrolling.

@Barmar I think that some locale issue.. I had that happening too when copying or editing code- inplace in some locale considered "exotic" by StEx
